# AppActive does not work in CScript when called as a process in C#

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, vbscript, process

I am running a VBS file as a ScriptHost that executes the input script at runtime.

```
Do While True
Dim script
script = Wscript.StdIn.ReadLine
On Error Resume Next

Execute(script)

If Err.Number <> 0 Then
  msgbox "ERROR"
End If

Err.Clear
On Error Goto 0
Loop
```

Here is the Process code

```
public class ScriptExecutor : IDisposable
{
     private Process cscriptProcess;

     public ScriptExecutor()
     {
        var commandArgment = "//Nologo \"c:\\Sample\\HostScript.vbs\"");
        ProcessStartInfo pb = new ProcessStartInfo("cscript.exe", commandArgment);
        pb.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        pb.RedirectStandardInput = true;
        pb.RedirectStandardError = true;
        pb.UseShellExecute = false;
        pb.CreateNoWindow = true;
        this.process = new Process();
        this.process.StartInfo = pb;
        this.process.Start();
    }

    public virtual void ExecuteScript(string newScript)
    {
        this.cscriptProcess.StandardInput.WriteLine(newScript);
        this.cscriptProcess.StandardInput.Flush();
    }
}
```

When I create ScriptExecutor instance just before ExecuteScript was called, the script below works fine.
However, when I create ScriptExecutor instance in another method, the script does not work.

```
Set objWshShell = CreateObject("Wscript.shell")
objWshShell.AppActive "MyApp"
```

Here is the code that worked.

```
public class RunScript 
{
    private  ScriptExecutor executor = null;

    public RunScript()
    {
    }

    public void Execute(string script)
    {
        executor = new ScriptExecutor();
        executor.ExecuteScript(script);
    }
}
```

And here is the code that not worked. MyApp does not have focus, but rather blinks in the taskbar.

```
public class RunScript 
{
    private  ScriptExecutor executor = null;

    public RunScript()
    {
        executor = new ScriptExecutor();
    }

    public void Execute(string script)
    {
        executor.ExecuteScript(script);
    }
}
```

Is there any difference between these two cases?

Comment: Your VBScript code is wrong. There is no active method only `AppActivate`. Even if right it is a wrapper around `SetForegroundWindow` which has rules about when you can do so. See Remarks section at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setforegroundwindow

Comment: I think the worked code because instance created and used in same thread, so the  requirement "the user is working with same window" is met

Comment: It's about windows not threads.